# Setting up PostgreSQL database on Mac

Tags: database, postgresql, homebrew, pgadmin

I'm having trouble connecting the Pgadmin tool to my PostgreSQL server that I have running on my own machine (I know it's probably something extremely easy but I've been Googling and I can't find a decent step by step guide, after being stuck for an hour I guess help is appreciated).

I installed PostgreSQL with Homebrew and managed to get it running using the command

```
postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres
```

Using psql I can see that it is working but I can't find the info to add the server on PgAdmin

[image]

I believe the main problem is with the host, what should I use? If it's specific to my computer, how can I find this information?

Once again I know this is probably straight forward for most of you but I guess it will help new users in the future like myself. If more information is necessary please let me know.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `localhost` for the host or the equivalent IP `127.0.0.1`.